# web notification on Click open new tab in safari extensions

Tags: safari-extension

How to open URL in `new tab` when clicking on `web notification`, came from safari extension.

I have two notifications n1 and n2, click on notification n1, nz should open "`example1.com`", "`example2.com`" in new tab.

Code:

```
var n1= new Notification("hi user");
n1.onclick() = function(){ var url = "example1.com";   // open new tab };
n1.show();

var n2= new Notification("hi user"});
n2.onclick() = function(){ var url = "example2.com";   // open new tab };
n2.show();
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH17-SW1

Comment: can you provide working sample..